# How to bin data from multiple column using pandas/python at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bins

I am working with a data frame that has 92 columns and 200000 rows. I want to bin and count data from each of these columns and put it in a new data frame for further plotting/analysis.

I'm using

```
bins = [-800, -70, -60, -50, -40, -30, -20, -5, 0]
df['Depth.1'].value_counts(bins=bins, sort = False)
```

which successfully bins data but only for one column at a time. Is it possible to do this for multiple columns in a data frame and put it into a new data frame?

Thanks

Comment: How do you propose handling the situation where 1 column places the result in bin1 and the next column places the result in bin2?

Comment: I'm not quite sure if i understand this. But I need to apply common bins to all columns (For my purpose, it is ok that the bin interval is common for all columns) and like to analyze the result i.e value counts for each bin interval. Could this value count be created as a new data frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to perform the same operation on each column. try

```
new_df = df.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(bins=bins, sort=False))
```

With an example, if all the columns are not going to be binned:

```
#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[3,6,2,7,3], 
                   'b':[2,1,5,8,9], 
                   'c':list('abcde')})
```

if you do the above method, you'll get an error as a column is of type string. So you can define a list of columns and do:

```
list_cols = ['a','b'] #only the numerical columns
new_df = df[list_cols].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(bins=[0,2,5,10], sort=False))
print(new_df)
               a  b
(-0.001, 2.0]  1  2
(2.0, 5.0]     2  1
(5.0, 10.0]    2  2
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. I tried the suggested method but it does not work. I'm getting some error. I wonder where exactly do we give an argument about selecting all columns in your command. Just to inform you I'm a beginner in python/pandas and willing to learn :)

Comment: Hi, Thank you for explaining with example, it does work now :). However, I've 92 columns for which i need to apply this operation. Is there a command by which we can choose all the columns in the dataframe rather than mentioning each of these columns in the list. For instance list_cols = ['a', 'b', 'c'....'92']

Comment: @Omi you can get all the columns with `list_cols = df.columns`, but if the the original answer did not work for you, then when specifying all the columns like this it will through the same error. do you have somewhere in your data some non-numerical data?

Comment: Ok, I understand. I've one column with non-numerical data. So just removed that one from CSV file and read CSV file again that only has columns with numerical values and your previous answer also works now. Thanks so much...appreciate your quick response :)

Comment: Ok...I did accept the answer. Please let me know if there is something more that I need to do. Thanks again.